# Not able to setup Deep linking or Universal linking for ios app

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am a newbie in ios development and working on Universal deep-linking.
I have added apple-app-site-association file to my website. (I have validated the file)
Client enabled Associated Domains feature for the app and added me as a team member. 
He has an individual account and sent me an invitation for the app.

I have a couple of questions:

- Do I need to enable signing with my account (created by invitation) for Universal deep linking to work in the development phase?
- If yes then Issue is that I am getting "Your development team, "Bhaskar Dabhi", does not support the Associated Domains capability." maybe because he couldn't enable access to certificates, identifiers and profiles. Does he need to enable "access to certificates, identifiers and profiles" for me to Universal deep linking to work?
- if No then Universal deep linking is not working. not sure why.

I went through a couple of tutorials but couldn't figure out if it's because of signing in.

Comment: Try to delete all your existing provisioning profiles for the given bundle id and download the new ones

Comment: Did you enable the Associated Domains capability in your certificates from the apple development account? if No, then you should have to enable it from there otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: @Muneebali I don't have that option to enable. Client enabled it for the app but he couldn't enable "access to certificates, identifiers, and profiles" while sending me to invite because he has an individual developer account. 

I am not getting any such option on my apple dev account.

Comment: @manishsharma93 will try that

Comment: @BhaskarDabhi ok then just tell the client to enable it t in certificates

Answer (score 1):

**Universal Links**

**Step 1:** Register your app at developer.apple.com.

**Step 2:** Enable ‘Associated Domains’ on your app identifier.

[image]

**Step 3:** Enable ‘Associated Domain’ on in your Xcode project.

[image]

**Step 4:** Configure your website to host the ‘apple-app-site-association’ file

**AASA (apple-app-site-association) File**

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": “*****.com.*****.ios",
        "paths": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Step 5:** Host your AASA file on your domain. After validating it using AASA validator.

**Refer**: https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/